# Calculating n'th Fibonacci number through golden ratio

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

Prove that $\frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$ rounded off to the nearest integer gives the n'th Fibonacci number, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167205/solving-fibonaccis-term-using-golden-ratio-convergance?rq=1) for an answer to the same question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving Fibonaccis Term Using Golden Ratio Convergance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167205/solving-fibonaccis-term-using-golden-ratio-convergance)